# A HTML Form was not posting the values from its fields to an Aspx page

Tags: html, forms, post, get

```
<form class="form-inline" action="targetSite.aspx">
   <input type="text" id="email"/>              
   <button type="submit">Sign up</button>
</form>
```

So the problem I was having was that the button would redirect to the appropriate 'tragetSite.aspx' page, but the value of the input with id='email' was not being passed.

I even changed the form's 'method' to 'post' but that didn't help.

I tried searching StackOverflow but I only found answers to more advanced problems.

Comment: You should post the solution as an answer (below).

Comment: Just did, and this is my first question so be nice guys :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I should post an answer for completeness

**Solution**: put a 'name' attribute in the input tag e.g.
`<input type="text" id="email" name="email"/>` and then the value of the input field will get sent

Hope this helps someone as well as myself if I ever make such a silly mistake again :D